# Hiding 2 tabs in a tab container feasible?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Hey guys I'm running into a weird issue.. Basically, a user logs into a page and based on his role status(admin or user) determines how many tabs he sees in a tabcontainer. If he is just a "user" then tab index 0 and 1 need to be hidden because they contain admin only functionality.

Doing this is simple:

```
if(user)
{
  Container.Tabs[0].visible = false;
  Container.Tabs[1].visible = false;
}
```

However the problem is if I set more than 1 tab index to visible = false the entire container disappears. Could this be a bug? I know you can only have one tab visible at a time.

Is there a fix? Or should I use a multiview?

Thanks, Josh

Comment: I assume you're using the AJAX Control Toolkit?  Have you checked to make sure you have the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this might be a bug with the Ajax Control Toolkit, I tested with the latest version (.net 3.5) and was able to reproduce the problem.  It seems the toolkit doesn't like it when you set tab 0 to visible, the number of other visible/invisible tabs doesn't matter.

I would suggest that you work around this by doing:

```
if(user)
{
   Container.Tabs.Remove(0);
   Container.Tabs.Remove(1);
}
```

This has the same effect, and since your tabs are defined via the ASPX markup doing a postback without the remove calls will result in your tabs reappearing (if you needed to reshow them for some reason).

Comment: No, this code is removing the tabs from the tab collection, rather than simply trying to make them invisible.

Answer (score 1):

```
Container.Tabs[0].enabled = false
```

this is the best solution I've come up with...

Comment: This disables tab, not hiding it.